# session logout issue in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
if ($this->Adminmodel->chck_login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password')) =="true")
{
    redirect("admin/index");
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your question, just bad formatted code. You should provide a question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to logout - session clear, you can use following code in to your Controller. Here userData is the array that u set the data of the session.

```
public function logout() {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('token');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('userData');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('admin/index');
}
```